# MongoDB: query Array for 'true' value at index n

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I have this collection containing a field "weekdays" representing weekdays Monday-Sunday (checked or not checked):

```
  var collection = [

    // work week (Monday to Friday)
    {
      weekdays: [true, true, true, true, true, false, false]
    },

    // weekend
    {
      weekdays: [false, false, false, false, false, true, true]
    },

    // ...

  ];
```

Now, how can I query this collection to find all items that has `true` for a specified weekday?

My first attempt was to use something like this:

// $elemMatch...

```
'weekdays[0]': true // Monday
```

But it did not seem to work. I'm out of ideas atm and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Don't claim to ask about 'truthy' while actually asking about 'true' - they're different things!

Comment: @ErwinWessels yeah, my humble apology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code

```
db.collectin.find({'weekdays.0' : true})
```

and if you want check 2 days:

```
db.collectin.find({$and : 
    [
        {'weekdays.0' : true},
        {'weekdays.1' : true}
    ]
})
```