# Mongoose search item in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose Schema like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

   name: String,
   email: String,
   data: [String],
});
```

And using Mongoose search I want to compare some value with the first element of data, im trying something like:

```
users.FindOne({data[0]: value}, {}, function(err, resp){
  //code
});
```

That of course doesen't work, how can I compare a value with the n element of an array?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916396/mongodb-query-array-for-truthy-value-at-index-n/26916537#26916537

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numeric indexes in your keys, but you need to use dot notation:

```
users.FindOne({'data.0': value}, {}, function(err, resp){
  //code
});
```